# OpenGL: how do I find the right scaling factor after loading a 3d model(say obj files)?

Tags: opengl, 3d, blender, assimp

I followed a tutorial（https://learnopengl.com/Model-Loading/Model） to load 3d objects（obj files） and rendering it with OpenGL. It works well except the size of the model.

When I read the obj files, I realized that the 3D objects might not be modeled within the same coordinates range(ideally all within [-1, 1]). So after loaded, they appears in various size(some are too huge to display).

My question: is there a good way to find the right scale of different models? Also is it better to build the object within [-1, 1] and let users to scale it as needed?

Comment: many models use physical coordinates (e.g. in meters) -- if this is the case you don't need any scaling. What's the right thing in your application really depends on your situation.

Answer (score 2):

One of the way is to move the camera accordingly with the height of the 3d object you are loading.

**step1:** you have to calculate the bounds and height and width of the object while loading the model.

**step2:** Based on the height of the object and field of view of the camera you can exactly calcualte the required 'z' value of the camera eye position.

[image]

By using tan we can actually find the distance and move camera accordigly.

Actually there is typo in that image you have to consider only half of the object height inorder to get t
he correct value.

Answer (score 1):

If the model comes from a modeling program that works (by default) with a different system unit *(e.g. centimeters instead of meters, because that's how UE4 likes them and/or that's how someone configured it),* then the model will either be very large, or very small.

Luckily, almost nobody uses imperial units for models (inches, feet, etc). So it's very easy to convert something from **cm** to **m**, to **km**, and back, since it works in 100 and 1000 increments/decrements.

```
const glm::mat4 model = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.01f)); // 100 times smaller
```

To avoid having to do this extra calculation, you could just load the model in Blender, select it, press the "S" key, begin typing "0.01" (without the quotes) and press enter.

You can also select the model, press "N" and set the exact dimensions in the panel on right side of the screen.

[image]